# Firebase push notification iOS 15 not receive

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios15

iOS app gets firebase push notification in iOS 14 but not receive in iOS 15.

this code is working for iOS 14 any new configuration about iOS 15:

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("requestAuthorization Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome on Stack Overflow. 
Please, check the guidelines on how to ask questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 

You will increase the chance to have an answer if the question is written correctly. 

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to re-upload the apns token `.p8` in your firebase project cloud messaging configuration. It's the second time its happened to me.